# Understanding Dynamic Fragment Loading

Tags: android, dynamic, android-fragments

In the Android Tutorial, under [Building a Flexible UI](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html), the Fragment instantiation given in the example happens in an Activitiy's `onCreate()` as follows:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.news_articles);

    // Check that the activity is using the layout version with
    // the fragment_container FrameLayout
    if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {

        ...

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
    }
}
```

Without including the `if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null)` check, my own example fails on startup with:

> IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

My question is:

*What does the if check do? I don't understand the commented explanation in the tutorial example. My understanding is that for some reason, the onCreate() is being called **more than once** during the activity lifecycle, but I don't know why? My knowledge of the activity lifecycle is admittedly minimal.*

Answer (score 2):

> What does the if check do?

It checks to see if the container exists. You cannot add a fragment to a container that does not exist.

Comment: But why are there occasions, in this single-activity, single-fragment app in which onCreate() gets called before the container exists? i.e. Why is onCreate being called more than once in the first place, all that should be happening is that the app's main activity get's called, once.

Comment: @Navonod: "But why are there occasions, in this single-activity, single-fragment app in which onCreate() gets called before the container exists?" -- it's not a single-fragment app. It's a single-fragment app on `-small` and `-normal` devices. The previous step of the tutorial set up multiple static fragments on `-large` and `-xlarge` devices. Hence, not all `setContentView()` calls will wind up with this container, due to different layouts being loaded based on screen size.

Comment: @Navonod: "Why is onCreate being called more than once in the first place, all that should be happening is that the app's main activity get's called, once." -- `onCreate()` will be called not only when the activity is initially created, but when it is re-created on a configuration change.

Answer (score 0):

it is simple Navonod,

```
if (findViewById(R.id.**fragment_container**) != null) {

  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.**fragment_container**,firstFragment).commit();

}
```

in res/layout/news_articles.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

So it is already created by the first time the app calls the theme up, this is why we check `findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null`. However, if you dynamically delete it during app runtime, this code will ensure you get it back safely into a FrameLayout that fragments should reside in.

P.S: there isn't actually two calls for onCreate here :)